# getTableRow() return an index larger than items' size

Tags: java, javafx

I create a TreeView, and set items to a `ObservableList<ColumnLine>`. And I add a listener to EditingCell, when I press `TAB` I can edit next column or next line's first column（And will append a new item to item list).

I don't know why it will return an index larger than items' size sometimes. Actually there is a column's cell value is a button, it will show on the larger row when I press `TAB`(edit next column), and press `TAB` again it will show back to the correct row.

#### Error:

When I press `TAB` it will return an index of row which larger than items' size.

**Print something when startEdit() is called**:

```
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    if (textField == null) createTextField();
    textField.setText(getString());
    setGraphic(textField);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    Platform.runLater(
        () -> {
          textField.requestFocus();
          textField.selectAll();
          System.out.println(
              "start: "
                  //+ getTableColumn().getText()
                  + " row-"
                  + getIndex()
                  + " column-"
                  + getTableView().getColumns().indexOf(getTableColumn())
                  + " item count-"
                  + getTableView().getItems().size());
          System.out.println("item-size: " + getTableView().getItems().size());
        });
  }
```

**Output:**

```
                                            -- First Line: normal
start:  row-0 column-1 item count-1
item-size: 1
commit:  row-0 column-1 item count-1
start:  row-0 column-2 item count-1
item-size: 1
commit:  row-0 column-2 item count-1
size: 2
                                            -- Second Line: wrong
start:  row-23 column-1 item count-2      <------ This
item-size: 2
start:  row-1 column-1 item count-2
item-size: 2
commit:  row-1 column-1 item count-2
start:  row-1 column-2 item count-2
item-size: 2
commit:  row-1 column-2 item count-2
database next: row-1 col-名
size: 3
                                            -- Third Line: wrong
start:  row-22 column-1 item count-3      <------ This
item-size: 3
start:  row-2 column-1 item count-3
item-size: 3
commit:  row-2 column-1 item count-3
start:  row-2 column-2 item count-3
item-size: 3
commit:  row-2 column-2 item count-3
database next: row-2 col-名
size: 4
                                            -- Fourth Line: wrong
start:  row-3 column-1 item count-4
item-size: 4
commit:  row-21 column-1 item count-4      <------ This
start:  row-3 column-1 item count-4
item-size: 4
commit:  row-3 column-1 item count-4
start:  row-3 column-2 item count-4
item-size: 4
commit:  row-3 column-2 item count-4
```

#### And the code:

create a TableView:

```
    view.getColumns().add(new ColumnBuilder<ColumnLine>().createStringColumn("名", "name"));
    view.getColumns().add(new ColumnBuilder<ColumnLine>().createStringColumn("类型", "type"));
    view.getColumns().add(new ColumnBuilder<ColumnLine>().createStringColumn("长度", "length"));
    view.getColumns().add(new ColumnBuilder<ColumnLine>().createStringColumn("小数点", "decimal"));

    TableColumn<ColumnLine, Boolean> colNotNull = new TableColumn<>("不是 null");
    colNotNull.setCellFactory(param -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
    colNotNull.setCellValueFactory(
        param -> {
          ColumnLine value = param.getValue();
          BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty(value.isNotNull());
          property.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> value.setNotNull(newValue));

          return property;
        });
    view.getColumns().add(colNotNull);

    TableColumn<ColumnLine, Boolean> key = new TableColumn<>("键");
    key.getStyleClass().add("imageValueColumn");
    key.setCellFactory(
        param ->
            new TableCell<ColumnLine, Boolean>() {
              private final Button btn = new Button();

              {
                btn.getStyleClass().add("imageButton");
                btn.setOnAction(
                    event -> {
                      ColumnLine value = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                      value.setPK(!value.isPK());
                      if (value.isPK()) {
                        if (btn.getGraphic() == null) {
                          btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/resource/key.png")));
                        }
                      } else btn.setGraphic(null);
                    });
              }

              @Override
              protected void updateItem(Boolean value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);

                setGraphic(empty ? null : btn);
              }
            });
    key.setCellValueFactory(
        param -> {
          ColumnLine value = param.getValue();
          BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty(value.isPK());
          property.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> value.setPK(newValue));
          return property;
        });
    view.getColumns().add(key);
  }
```

Editing cell's key listener(getNextColumn(boolean) will return the next cell):

```
if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {

    // Get next cell
    TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(true);

    if (nextColumn != null) {
        // Not the last column
        if (nextColumn != getTableView().getColumns().get(1)) {
            getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), nextColumn);
        } else { // the last column
            // Not the last line
            if (getTableRow().getIndex() < getTableView().getItems().size() - 1) {
                // Edit next column
                getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex() + 1, nextColumn);
            } else { // The last line
                // Add a new item
                ((TableCreator) obj).getNewColumns().add(new ColumnLine());

                // Edit
                getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex() + 1, nextColumn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm not a English speaker...I apologize to you if there are something wrong within this post.

Comment: Tooooooooooo much code

Comment: this is too much of code. put the sample or the error where you are getting the error

Comment: sorry about that...I will lessen the code.

Comment: Did not read the code (must work), but maybe it has to do with paging: adding the number of reserved rows of a page.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for the answer. But what should I do?

Comment: Ok, seems to be work! I call tableView.refresh() after add a new item. But why table won't refresh automatically with a item of ObservableList?